# Limit the frame rate on an aframe project

Tags: three.js, aframe, frame-rate

I am developing an aframe project on my MacBook pro, late 2013. When running the project, the fan of my computer always spins fast, regardless which browser I use (firefox, safari, chrome) and the project size (also happens with a project just containing a simple a-box).

aframe-stats show me that my project (1028244 vertices, 342748 faces) still runs with 20 fps.

Is it somehow possible to limit the frame rate to 10fps in order to keep my computer quite? Or any other way to limit the flop-consumption of the aframe project? I already tried a native approach with `sudo cputhrottle plugin-container 10` but that did not just throttle the aframe-renderer but the whole firefox browser. Can I pull the break somewhere in the JavaScript or the Browser settings?

Comment: You could always throttle execution by checking a counter and only executing and resetting when it hits 10? Or when the duration of the frame is finally larget than 1000/10?

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without your project code. Large data sets will simply crank out even a high spec macbook pro. I have found it helpful to pause any rendering whenever possible to quiet the users' machines.

I personally removed automated next animation frame rendering in favor of waiting for controls and objects to change.

For example:

this.controls.addEventListener( 'change', function(e){  addToRenderStack(); });

A simple function addtorenderstack puts in a new value in a list for a render, with the expectation that the render will occur at some point in the future and not right away. the list can also be used to log who requested the render in the call stack, and narrow down performance hogs.

addtorenderstack places a render request in a list. In the requestanimationframe loop, if the list has any length, a render is called on the scene. The stack is immediately cleared rather than processed one by one. If controls or animations continue to make render requests, the list will have a length again and request animationframe will process them in the same way with another render.

In this way, the code only renders when absolutely required. This saved me much grinding on framerate and the fans only come on during intensive operations and then shutdown when its complete, much like a typical 3d game experience.

Your mileage may vary depending on what's happening in your app. I work in engineering so often the view of the 3d world is stopped as an engineer examines or shows a model.